# How to dockerize Firebase emulator with firestore and functions

Tags: firebase, docker, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I am using Firebase for my React app.

Of course Firebase does not have official docker image, but I found this one `spine3/firebase-emulator` which was enough for auth and firestore.

I can run auth and firestore using this command:
`docker run -d -p=9000:9000 -p=8080:8080 -p=4000:4000 -p=9099:9099 -p=8085:8085 -p=5001:5001 -p=9199:9199 --env "GCP_PROJECT=******" --env "ENABLE_UI=true" --name emulator spine3/firebase-emulator`

===

BUT, I want also implement firebase functions.

My vision: I want to have some repo called `backend`, `dockerfile`, `docker-compose.yml`, and folder with firebase functions `functions`. I want to run `docker-compose up` which will build functions, put them into local functions emulator, and also will set local firestore, and local auth.

I spent few days trying different github repos that trying to set up emulator inside the docker, talking with copilot and gpt, but I didn't come up with something workable.

Has anybody done such thing ever? Could you point me how to do it, maybe some resources?

Answer (score 1):

So I end up putting different pieces of different github repos together to make it work, and documented it in my repo.

For all people that also struggle:
https://github.com/andreyka26-git/firebase-docker-emulators/tree/main

There I set functions, auth, firestore, pubsub together inside the docker.
One `docker compose up -d` and it works.